# Byte class object to Json

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following byte variable, which I am trying to parse to become JSON.

```
payload = b'{\n  "time" : "2021-03-09T02:14:13.312Z",\n    "age" : 56,\n    "trackingMode" : "PERMANENT_TRACKING",\n    "number" : 4.0,}'

payload_decoded = codecs.decode(payload, 'utf-8')
json_record = json.load(payload_decoded, parse_float=Decimal)
print(json_record)
```

It's returning this error.. How can I parse my byte var above to Json? Thank You!

[ERROR] AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: you can just do: `json.loads(payload.decode())` You need `load**s**` not `load`

Comment: Thank you alot... simple mistake, that i just seem to overlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
json_record = json.loads(payload_decoded, parse_float=Decimal)
```

Explanation: [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) expects a file handle that contains JSON, whereas [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) expects a string or bytes.

Comment: Thank you alot... simple mistake, that i just seem to overlook.